# Implementing localization in an existing application

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows

I have an .net application, which as separate Business Object Layer, Data Access Layer and UI. All are spread across different solution files as the middle tier is reused as required. We set date some times in UI Layer, Business Object Layer, Data Access Layer. Now we are planning to implement localization as we are rolling out it to multiple locations. What is the best way to do it, I dont want to find where we are setting dates across all layers and change them to set at one common place, that is a cumbersome way to do. Any suggestions on achieving this in a optimal way without changing code. Application is in both windows and web version.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are saving dates in date objects you should not have any problems. The translation is made on the local computer. Each computer has its own regional settings, but they will stored the same in a datetime object. If have multiple timezones, you should first findout what the business requirements are for displaying the date/time (local or place of origin etc).